what does "op":"STOP" in StructLogs in debug_traceTransaction mean
Running debug_traceTransaction, I get
{"id":1,
"jsonrpc":"2.0",
"result":{"gas":"0x5f84",
  "structLogs":
     [{"depth":1,
       "error":"",
       "gas":"0x130d948",
       "gasCost":3,
       "memory": [],
       "op":"PUSH1",
       "pc":0,
       "stack":[],
       "storage":{}},

       ...

      {"depth":1,
       "error":"",
       "gas":"0x130bbc6",
       "gasCost":0,
       "memory": ["0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000080"],
       "op":"STOP",
       "pc":770,
       "stack":["00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000f2fde38b"],"storage":{"0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000":"0000000000000000000000000d9b0ac615c4f77e7942fb8932aaa306275679cf"}}],
       "returnValue":"",
       "storage":{}}}

Why is the "op" here is "STOP"?  And why is "returnValue":"" here?
Does it mean that the transaction failed?

No, the transaction did not fail. Actually this response shows, that the transaction was successful. The STOP basically says that the transaction has finished - in case of an error you would see the error property populated with f.e. REVERT or INVALID. The STOP also consumes 0 gas. The returnValue is empty because the function did not return any data, in case if it would, you would get the returned data from the transaction in this field.
You can reference different Opcodes, like the STOP, for example here.
You can test yourself with a function like this:
contract Test {
    function testStopOpCode() external {}
}

You can see the STOP in the debug logs, and you may also verify that the STOP call uses 0 gas.
